# How to change the color of JTable row after clicking a button

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I want to change the color of `JTable` row after clicking a button. I found many examples that show how to initiate a table with different colors of rows, and also how to change the color on selecting a row. However, I wonder what is the right way to change the color on clicking a JButton.

```
TableCellRenderer colorRenderer = new ColorRenderer();
table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, colorRenderer);

private class ColorRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
            JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        if (hasFocus) {
            setBackground(Color.cyan);
        } else if (isSelected) {
            setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
            setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you are loading data in `JTable` as :

```
public void fillTable(){
       List<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
       List<String[]> values = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        columns.add("col1");
        columns.add("col2");
        columns.add("col3");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            values.add(new String[] {"val"+i+" col1","val"+i+" col2","val"+i+" col3"});
        }
        TableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(values.toArray(new Object[][] {}), columns.toArray());
        tableName.setModel(tableModel);
    }
```

Then, you can use like this class to set a rendered to `JTable`  :

```
public class EvenOddRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

        public static final DefaultTableCellRenderer DEFAULT_RENDERER = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            DEFAULT_RENDERER.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            Component renderer = DEFAULT_RENDERER.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                    table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            ((JLabel) renderer).setOpaque(true);
            Color foreground, background;
            Color alternate = new Color(0xC0, 0xC0, 0xF0);
            Color lightBlue = new Color(204, 204, 255);

            if (isSelected) {
                foreground = Color.black;
                background = Color.gray;
            } else {
                if (row % 2 == 0) {
                    foreground = Color.black;
                    background = Color.white;
                } else {
                    foreground = Color.black;
                    background = lightBlue;
                }
            }
            renderer.setForeground(foreground);
            renderer.setBackground(background);
            return renderer;
        }
    }
```

Like this :

```
  TableCellRenderer renderer = new EvenOddRenderer();
  tableName.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, renderer);
  tableName.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
```

[image: JTable on load]

Then you can use `setRowSelectionInterval()` method to select any row :

```
     private void btn(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
      int index = 0; 
      tableName.setRowSelectionInterval(index, index);
     }
```

Here you are selecting the first row in `JTable`

[image: JTable after button click]

In this example, you are choosing `Color.gray` as `JTable` selection color

You can change it for sure

Comment: Thank you. When I apply this renderer and load data, it says "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError". Do you have any idea why it happens?

Comment: Now it works. The colors are changed on loading the data.  However when I click on button, the color of a row is not changed. So, I assume that "isSelected" is not passed to the renderer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/).

This approach will also work for tables that contain different data types in each column so you don't have to create custom renderers for every type of data.